# Read JSON values from URL via PHP

Tags: php, json, url, decode

i have url with this simple JSON `{"result":true,"data":[{"Position":"135"}]}`

I tried to read it with this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://...link/here..');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->result[1]->data->Position;
```

but it not works. Where i do a mistake? Thanks for helping!

Comment: post sample url

Comment: @isa424 file_get_contents works with http request, if it is not disabled

Comment: you are accessing it wrong. use echo $obj->data[0]->Position;.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrectly addressing the data in the PHP object created from the JSON String

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://...link/here..');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->data[0]->Position;
```

Or if there are more occurances

```
foreach ( $obj->data as $idx=>$data) {
    echo $data->Position;
}
```

Comment: Very accurate answer, but how can we implement load more function? for example, if we have 1000 more data how can we split to show 15 each and then show load more button to click and show another 15 so on... til we reach the end of the data

Comment: @amprie286 That sounds like Pagination. There are lots of tutorials out there on that subject